# asp.net mvc guidance on how to architect an employee review application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Somewhat new to asp.net mvc and need a little guidance.  I'm using asp.net mvc 5 and EF6.  I'm developing an employee review application which has around 10 employee review forms.  Within these 10 forms there are subsets for non-manager, manager, director, etc..  Depending on employee position level the appropriate review form should be shown.  There are ***some*** common sections throughout the forms.

**Model**

```
public enum ReviewTypes : int
{
    NonMgrReview= 1,
    NonMgrSelfEval,
    ManagerReview,
    ManagerSelfEval
}

public class Review
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public ReviewTypes ReviewType { get; set; }
    public string Reviewer_Name { get; set; }        
    public string EmployeeBeingReviewed_Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string OverallPerformance { get; set; }        
}
```

Should each review form be a view so I'd end up with 10 views?  Then have if/else logic to return view depending on employee level in the controller actions?  Something like:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        // logic to return view based on employee level          
            if (employee.IsNonManager)
            {
                return View("NonManager");
            }
            else if (employee.IsManager)
            {
                return View("Manager");
            }
            // ....                           

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Any advice and guidance is much appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use partial views to render any non-common parts, having something like this in your main view: `@if(employee.IsManager) 
{
    @Html.Partial("Manager")
}`

Comment: Thanks Joe.  So I can create several "main" views and within those have partial views. The controller will have logic that will return the main view.  Does this sound like a good approach?

Comment: Yes, although you commonly see the opposite where people put the common/reusable parts of the views in partial views and render them whereever they need them.

Comment: My approach would be to create individual view models having a base view model composed of all common properties and based on the logged in person fill the viewmodel with data. Same goes for views AS @Joe has suggested based on the employee role and viewmodel we can decide to render the particular partial in main view